# ayuda para limpiar este codigo en python

Tags: python

```py
# Comparacion entre 2 numeros e imprimir el mayor
print("Comparacion de números enteros")

while True:
    try:        
        num1 = int(input("Ingrese el primer numero entero: "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        print("Numero valido")
        break
while True:
    try:        
        num2 = int(input("Ingrese el segundo numero entero: "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        print("Numero valido")
        break
```

Me gustaria simplificar el codigo y que quede una variable para el chequeo de que el input es siempre un numero entero, lamentablemte no lo consigo solo me ha funcionado de esta forma, soy bastante novato acepto cualquier sugerencia y/o critica, gracias

Comment: ¿Qué falla? ¿Qué quieres decir con _que quede una variable para el chequeo_?

Answer (score 1):

Una simple mejora sería extraer el código repetido a una función:

```
def input_numero(msg):
    while True:
        try:        
            num = int(input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            print("Numero valido")
            return num

# Se usará así:
num1 = input_numero("Ingrese el primer numero entero: ")
num2 = input_numero("Ingrese el segundo numero entero: ")
```

Pero aún así el interior de la función no tiene un código muy limpio, con esos `try/except/else`. Otra posibilidad, en lugar de excepciones, consiste en mirar si el input del usuario realmente es un número, antes de intentar convertirlo en entero. Es lo que se conoce como "pedir permiso en lugar de pedir disculpas" :-)

Con esta técnica la función quedaría asi:

```
def input_numero(msg):
   while True:
      respuesta = input(msg)
      if respuesta.isdigit():
         print("Numero valido")
         return int(respuesta)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia, al usar mi codigo en una función es cuando me fallaba, la segunda función quedaba muy por encima de mi conocimiento pero me parece muy elegante y limpia, voy a probarla.

Comment: ¿Qué te fallaba?

Comment: Por un lado se queda en bucle infinito no se ejecutaba bien el break si encadenada los dos while true, por otro si la usaba con un unico while true no sabia como llamarla con dos valores distintos (num1, num2) con tu ejemplo que quedo muy claro (gracias) ``` # Se usará así:
num1 = input_numero("Ingrese el primer numero entero: ")
num2 = input_numero("Ingrese el segundo numero entero: ")